# Android - Send touch event to other views

Tags: android, layout, android-recyclerview

I am trying to achieve a scroll effect, I think it can be done because I see some apps implemented this.

I have a FrameLayout, in this layout I have:
- A recycler view
- A float view

```
<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

    <LinearLayout // float layout here
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="100dp">
    </LinearLayout>
</FrameLayout>
```

When I scroll the recycler view, I can see the float view scroll also, but when it reaches the top of the screen, I want it to stop there. I have successfully implemented this but after that I face to a new issue. Because the float view is above the recycler view, I can not scroll when touch and scroll the float view. In this case the float view seems consumes the touch event so that the recycler does nothing.

What I want to achieve is when user want to scroll the recycler view should consume it.
Im thinking of sending the float view's touch event to recycler view.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found same problem some time ago. Here is my solution (it is a little bit hacky, but didn't find better solution). Put in in your custom FrameLayout class:

```
public class CustomFrameLayout extends FrameLayout {

    ... 

    @InjectView(R.id.rv_details)
    RecyclerView recyclerView;

    @InjectView(R.id.ll_details_action_bar_wrapper)
    ViewGroup actionBarWrapperViewGroup;

    private List<MotionEvent> cachedEventList = new ArrayList<>();

    private boolean touchIsFromActionBar;

    private boolean yTranslationThresholdPassed;

    // Pawel Janeczek
    // Those two overrides is for forwarding touch events, that started on action bar, to recyclerview.
    // But you may ask, why there are so many lines? it should by only recyclerView.dispatchTouchEvent(ev) and it should be fine
    // It is because RecyclerView when it is starting scrolling it sends parent.requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent which disables sending onInterceptTouchEvent to parent
    // In such case we must set a flag touchIsFromActionBar when motion event starts and is in action bar, and then when this flag is set we remove calling super on requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent
    @Override
    public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
        int action = ev.getAction();
        if (action == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN && viewUtils.isWithinViewBounds(actionBarWrapperViewGroup, ev.getRawX(), ev.getRawY())) {
            touchIsFromActionBar = true;
        }
        if (touchIsFromActionBar && shouldDispatchEventToRecyclerView(ev)) {
            if (!listUtils.isEmpty(cachedEventList)) {
                for (MotionEvent motionEvent : cachedEventList) {
                    recyclerView.dispatchTouchEvent(motionEvent);
                }
                cachedEventList.clear();
            }
            recyclerView.dispatchTouchEvent(ev);
        }
        if (action == MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL || action == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
            cachedEventList.clear();
            yTranslationThresholdPassed = false;
            touchIsFromActionBar = false;
        }
        return false;
    }

    private boolean shouldDispatchEventToRecyclerView(MotionEvent event) {
        if (yTranslationThresholdPassed) {
            return true;
        } else if (listUtils.isEmpty(cachedEventList)) {
            cachedEventList.add(MotionEvent.obtain(event));
            return false;
        }

        int yTranslationThreshold = 2;

        MotionEvent lastEvent = listUtils.getLast(cachedEventList);
        if (Math.abs(lastEvent.getY() - event.getY()) > yTranslationThreshold) {
            yTranslationThresholdPassed = true;
            return true;
        } else {
            cachedEventList.add(MotionEvent.obtain(event));
            return false;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(boolean disallowIntercept) {
        if (!touchIsFromActionBar) {
            super.requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(disallowIntercept);
        }
    }
    ...
}
```

ViewGroup named actionBarWrapperViewGroup is a flow layout in your sample.

And xml for CustomFrameLayout:

```
<merge xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/rv_details"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            />

    <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/ll_details_action_bar_wrapper"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

        ...

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/ll_details_action_bar_container"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/default_bar_height"
            android:background="?colorPrimary"/>

        ...
    </LinearLayout>
</merge>
```

It is live copied from my project, so names can be misleading but I think it is understandable. If you have any questions go on.

Comment: Thank you, I will be back for the result.:)

Comment: Cool, It works as expected. :). Marked as answer. thank you.

Comment: I found a small issue with this (not a big problem). When you touch the "actionBarWrapperViewGroup" slightly and scroll, the recycler view is not scrolled. but it jumps immediately after scrolling amount of pixels.

Comment: Try to change yTranslationThreshold to 1. I think this should fix the problem